# how to optimize query searching for similar ids referenced in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

in my query here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nfJzZoYC5gEXLu8hrw4JT2/1

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT tc1.co_id), COUNT(DISTINCT tc2.co_id)
FROM test t
INNER JOIN test_corelation_1 tc1 ON tc1.test_id = t.id AND tc1.co_id IN (
    SELECT co_id 
    FROM test_corelation_1
    WHERE test_id IN (1, 2, 5)
    GROUP BY co_id
)
INNER JOIN test_corelation_2 tc2 ON tc2.test_id = t.id AND tc2.co_id IN (
    SELECT co_id 
    FROM test_corelation_2
    WHERE test_id IN (1, 2, 5)
    GROUP BY co_id
)
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY (COUNT(DISTINCT tc1.co_id) + COUNT(DISTINCT tc2.co_id)) ASC;
```

i am trying getting all the ids from table `test` that shares similar ids corelated to the `ids 1, 2, 3` then sorting it by the least similar by counting it which results in this

| id | COUNT(DISTINCT tc1.co_id) | COUNT(DISTINCT tc2.co_id) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 |

but it gets very very slow the more ids i am checking for its similarities and i do not know how to optimize it further from this and i thought of using CTE but it had same results in the optimizer explain

Comment: The two `GROUP BY co_id` are superfluous. Maybe removing them already speeds up the query. You are using column names called `co_id`, so can we assume there is a related table (maybe called corelation) in your database? Using that could speed up the query immensely.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes unique on correlation name and primary id - why is grouping to remove duplicate is superfluous in this query? - it removes many duplicates that will be counted in the `IN` or does not work in  like this?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it removed the materialization and made it primary after adding the correlation

Comment: With `IN` you tell the DBMS what you want. If you use `DISTINCT` (or a `GROUP BY` that doesn't do anything else but `DISTINCT`) you are trying to tell the DBMS how to do that. This is something we don't want to do. The DBMS has a built-in optimizer that can decide whether it seems better to make the values distinct first (which can be a costly sort operation) or not.

Comment: As to my question: You misunderstood. What I want to know is: is there another table you are not showing? The name `co_id` in the two tables suggest that this is the case. I.e. that their test_id points to the test table and their co_id to some co or corelation table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes but useless in this query because just names

Comment: Yep, now that I thought about how to write the query, I noticed that, too. You are right, the corelation table doesn't help here. Neither does the test table, though :-) Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main means we have to speed up queries are indexes. But of course we should ensure that our queries are as straight-forward as possible. In your case you don't need the test table at all. Just get your counts from the two other tables and join them. As you are only interested in test IDs that exist in both tables, this is a mere inner join.

```
select test_id, c1.count_1, c2.count_2
from
(
  select test_id, count(*) as count_1
  from test_corelation_1
  where co_id in (select co_id from test_corelation_1 where test_id in (1, 2, 5))
  group by test_id
) c1
join
(
  select test_id, count(*) as count_2
  from test_corelation_2
  where co_id in (select co_id from test_corelation_2 where test_id in (1, 2, 5))
  group by test_id
) c2 using (test_id)
order by c1.count_1 + c2.count_2, test_id;
```

I recommend these indexes for the query:

```
create index idx1 on test_corelation_1 (co_id, test_id);
create index idx2 on test_corelation_2 (co_id, test_id);
```

(In case the DBMS wants to work with indexes on (co_id, test_id), too, it already has these indexes, as these are the tables' primary keys.)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have written the query in a very awkward way.  I would write it this way, using direct joins to subqueries which find the counts for the two test correlation tables:

```sql
SELECT t.id, COALESCE(tc1.cnt1, 0) AS cnt1, COALESCE(tc2.cnt2, 0) AS cnt2
FROM test t
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT co_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt1
    FROM test_corelation_1
    WHERE test_id IN (1, 2, 5)
    GROUP BY co_id
) tc1
    ON tc1.test_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT co_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt2
    FROM test_corelation_2
    WHERE test_id IN (1, 2, 5)
    GROUP BY co_id
) tc2
    ON tc2.test_id = t.id
ORDER BY cnt1 + cnt2;
```

Count queries are notoriously difficult to optimize, but the subqueries above have a `WHERE` clause, so the following indices might help:

```sql
CREATE INDEX tc_idx_1 ON test_corelation_1 (test_id, co_id);
CREATE INDEX tc_idx_1 ON test_corelation_2 (test_id, co_id);
```

Comment: is not having the count in every row slow it in the joins because will calculate every time?